# Home ranges MCP too small in r (coordinate system problem?)

Tags: r, coordinates

I would like to calculate in r the home ranges of some squirrels using MCP and Kernel density functions. The coordinate systems are NAD 83 datum with UTM coordinate system. However the size of homeranges are unrealistically small. Where is the mistake?

[sample of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uE9Ar.png)

Here my code

```r
library("readxl")
library(adehabitatHR) # Load library
library(sp)

#read data 
telemetry<-read_excel("telemetrysp.xlsx",sheet = "Sheet1",na=c("NA"))#I need to tell to read NA as an actual na value 

# SpatialPointsDataFrame objects don't like missing values
# Remove two rows with NA's
telemetry <- telemetry[!is.na(telemetry$LongitudeX) & !is.na(telemetry$LatitudeY),]

# Only include three columns (id, x, and y coordinates) for making MCP's
telemetry.mcp <- telemetry[, c("Squirrel ID", "LongitudeX", "LatitudeY")] 

# Create a SpatialPointsDataFrame by defining the coordinates

coordinates(telemetry.mcp) <- c("LongitudeX", "LatitudeY")

# Set the coordinate reference system (CRS)

#+nadgrids=@conus,@alaska,@ntv2_0.gsb,@ntv1_can.dat" )
proj4string(telemetry.mcp) <- CRS( "+init=epsg:4269")

# Calculate MCPs for each turtle
redsq.mcp <- mcp(telemetry.mcp, percent = 95)

# Examine output
redsq.mcp
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't projected your data. The `mcp()` function is treating your long/lat values as projected coordinates and that is why the values are so small. Compounding this is the fact that the default output of `mcp()` is set to hectares. The approach outlined below returns results in square metres e.g. `unout = "m2"`. You can adapt this if it does not suit your needs.

You will need to double-check whether the `CRS()` string I have used in `spTransform()` is correct for your data, including whether the UTM zone is the right one. Based on your example image, here is a repex showing the correct workflow:

```
library(adehabitatHR)
library(sp)

# A dummy df based on your example
set.seed(1)
telemetry.mcp <- data.frame(SquirrelID = rep(c(100, 200), each = 5),
                            LongitudeX = runif(10, -74.255, -74.25),
                            LatitudeY = runif(10, 44.4345, 44.4348))

# Define long/lat columns
coordinates(telemetry.mcp) <- c("LongitudeX", "LatitudeY")

# Set the coordinate reference system (CRS)
proj4string(telemetry.mcp) <- CRS("+init=epsg:4269")

# Find the UTM zone your data are in (for setting zone in next step)
floor((telemetry.mcp$LongitudeX + 180) / 6) + 1

# Project data (the step you missed)
telemetry.mcp <- spTransform(telemetry.mcp, 
                             CRS("+proj=utm +zone=18 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs"))

# Calculate MCPs for each squirrel
redsq.mcp <- mcp(telemetry.mcp, percent = 95, unout = "m2")

# Examine output, in m2
redsq.mcp

Object of class "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame" (package sp):
  
Number of SpatialPolygons:  2

Variables measured:
     id     area
100 100 1752.751
200 200 1565.907
```

Comment: Thank you so much! When I try to include that part, I obtain the following error: Error in spTransform(telemetry.mcp, CRS("+proj=utm +zone=18 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs")) : 
  sf required

Comment: I added the library(sf)  and the problem seems fixed!

Comment: @MarinaMorandini - that is curious, I didn't encounter that. What version of `adehabitatHR` and`sp` are you using? To find out, run `sessionInfo()` and look in the "other attached packages" section. Or if you are using RStudio, you can scroll though the "Packages" tab.